# ASP.Net Menu with Sub Menus

Tags: asp.net, menu, submenu

I would like to create a menu in my web application. This menu has just needs to be vertical, and be able to operate something like this:

[image]

It doesn't need to be a pop up menu or anything. Just a static menu that sits on the side of the page and allows you to browse through submenus as well. I am new to asp.net and not sure if such a control exists or even what it would be called. Could someone asit me in my doing this? Does such a control exist or do I need to create it?

Comment: you probably want something like a css menu http://cssmenumaker.com/

Comment: can you select an answer, or update on why nothing is suitable?

Comment: can you select an answer, or update on why nothing is suitable?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the standard ASP:Menu server control.

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="3" Orientation="Vertical">
  <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="File" Value="File">
      <asp:MenuItem Text="New" Value="New"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Open" Value="Open"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="Edit">
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Copy" Value="Copy"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Paste" Value="Paste"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="View" Value="View">
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Normal" Value="Normal"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Preview" Value="Preview"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying Michael.

Comment: It does not work as is. It shows a list of items just as if you had a single asp:Menu. Do you have .cs or .css to go with it? to make it work?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. There is no css or code-behind required. The oriiginal question was: `Just a static menu that sits on the side of the page and allows you to browse through submenus as well` My ASPX markup is exactly that. Please read the question before making incorrect comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript. There are already some plugins available.

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/

http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/22/create-simple-jquery-right-click-cross-browser-vertical-menu/

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

You can customize the CSS to look like the windows 7 menu

Answer (score 0):

The [Menu Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28VS.80%29.aspx) does this.

It's not as elegant as some javascript versions, but it works.

Since you say you're new, there are also plenty of videos showing how to use it, including [this one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=video&cd=3&ved=0CFQQtwIwAg&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgLZYgO8ad8&ei=4W89T93cJ4TF0QGooJGoBw&usg=AFQjCNGfMWkP5oMeauUtrAZ29-lf3fzHog).